# How to make storyboard autoreplay itself over and over again in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, storyboard, expression-blend

I have created storyboard in blend it autostarts when I go into certain page, but I would like to autoreplay it after it ends.
How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its simple..

Just hookup your storyboard completion event and in its completion event call play event again.

```
    // Like Here my storyboard is sbSquare
    private void sbSquare_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.sbSquare.Begin();
    }
```

Comment: Figured it out little bit differently(added second ControlStoryboardAction), but it helped : ). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

@Arslan suggested answer is work around not actual solution . You need to use RepeatedBehviour Property of Storyboard. Go through following link.

[Repeat Animation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753367.aspx)